# Conditional CKSubscription does not trigger notification

Tags: cloudkit, cksubscription

I have a `OUP` record type, and it has a `.DeleteSelf` reference to a `OU` record type.

If I just set up an **unconditional** subscription, that **works**:

```
let subscriptionOUP = CKSubscription(recordType: "OUP", predicate:NSPredicate(value: true), subscriptionID: "oup", options: .FiresOnRecordUpdate)
```

But the **conditional** way **not**:

```
let ekf = "oup-\(ou.recordID)"
let pr = NSPredicate(format: "ou = %@", CKReference(recordID: CKRecordID(recordName: organizationUser.recordID), action: .DeleteSelf))
let subscriptionOUP = CKSubscription(recordType: "OUP", predicate:pr, subscriptionID: ekf, options: .FiresOnRecordUpdate)
println("\(pr) \(ekf)")
```

Terminal content:

```
ou == <CKReference: 0x1558d3d0;51D56239-D68C-4E12-BD23-E4DCEF5721B7:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__)> 

oup-51D56239-D68C-4E12-BD23-E4DCEF5721B7
```

What is the problem with my predicate or subscriptionID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `subscriptionID` string is too long.

When you reduce it like this, it will work:

```
let ekf = "oup-\((organizationUser.recordID as NSString).substringToIndex(7))"
```

Comment: Yes I found this too! It silently fail without giving you any error. But the problem turns to be the length of subscription ID